# Power BI Calculated Column based on max date and a filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks as follows:

[image]

I am trying to do a calculated column, so that it is 1 when Attribute 1 is 'Actual' and is at the latest available date (eg 3 Nov in this example). The following DAX calculated column does not work, would anyone know why?

```
LastDateFilter = 
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date]),'Table'[Attribute 1]="Actual")

RETURN
    IF ('Table'[Date] = MaxDate, 1 ,0)
```

Comment: Your latest available date is 4 Nov. Could you please share the expected result you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood properly your question, you want a result like the image that you have provided.

I have changed some names and dates but keeping the structure.

This is my approach:

```
LastDateFilter = 
VAR MaxDate =
   CALCULATE (
     MAX ( 'Tabla'[Date]),FILTER('Tabla','Tabla'[At1]="Actual" && NOT 
     ISBLANK('Tabla'[At2])))

RETURN
    IF (('Tabla'[Date] == MaxDate &&'Tabla'[At1]=="Actual"), 1 ,0)
```

[image]

I put filter for clarify but is not necessary...
If you add data it works:

[image]